# Keep current menu item highlighted

Tags: css, menu

I have a menu setup on my page that loads items into an iframe. They are custom maps that replace the default Google map. My question is how do I get the menu item for the currently displaying item to remain highlighted?

```
<div id="right_col" class="clearfix">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="copperwood.html" target="iframe_map">Copperwood</a></li>
                <li><a href="canyoncrest.html" target="iframe_map">Canyon Crest/The Canyons</a></li>
                <li><a href="riverstone.html" target="iframe_map">Riverstone</a></li>
                <li><a href="garrystation.html" target="iframe_map">Garry Station</a></li>
                <li><a href="legacyridge.html" target="iframe_map">Legacy Ridge</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=217268423195093625679.0004cf68eb14897eb07b4&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=49.69371,-112.868754&amp;spn=0.086835,0.089951&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed" target="iframe_map">Overall Lethbridge</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#right_col ul{
position: relative;
list-style: none;
top: -17px;
}

#right_col ul a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
display: block;
padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;
margin: 10px;
background: #eeeeee;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}

#right_col ul a:hover{
background: #e9b900;
text-decoration: none;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example, you could look into JavaScript and see if that might help.

Answer (score 0):

1.give the first `li` tag a class such as `li class="active"..`

2.Go to your css and do this :

```
.active{
background-color:red; // example
}
```

3.then just open

```
script `type="text/javascript"`

$('li a').click(function()
{
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});


</script>
```